# Why can't we apply the distributive property like this?

Tags: arithmetic

If I do $3(6 + 9) = (3 \times 6) + (3 \times9)$, I get the correct answer.

But when I am doing $3 \times 6(6 + 9 -12) = (3 \times 6) + (3 \times 9) + (3 \times (-12)) + (6 \times 6) + (6 \times 9) + (6 \times(-12))$, I am getting $54$ and $27$ as the answers respectively. Please help me understand this, which rule is being applied here?

Comment: That's the expansion of $(3+6)*(6+9-12)$. Notice the operator between the 3 and the first 6.

Comment: @JonathanZ Then what will the expansion of 3x6(6+9−12)?

Comment: You would distribute 3x6 over (6+9-12) and get three terms: 3*6*6 + 3*6*9 - 3*6*12.

Comment: @JonathanZ Can you please explain why can't we multiply them separately? I mean, which rule is being applied here?

Comment: Alternatively, you could leave the 3 alone for the moment, and just distribute the 6, yielding 3*(6*6 + 6*9 - 6*12).

Comment: You can __only__ distribute multiplication over addition (or subtraction). In my first comment I am distributing multiplication by (3*6) over the three addition-or-subtraction terms.

Comment: You can't expand in your way because there are counterexamples, and you have discovered one.

Comment: And in my second version we do "multiply then separately" - first we distribute the "multiply by 6" to get the expression shown. We could then distribute the "multiply by 3", and I'll let you say what we would get after that.

Comment: @JonathanZ So we can do 3*6*6 + 3*6*9 - 3*6*12,
or 18*6 + 18*9 - 18*12, or 3*(6*6 + 6*9 - 6*12). Either we take both 3 and 6 numbers together, or do multiplication of 3 and 6 beforehand, or we can distribute 3 and 6 over (6+9-12)one by one. But we cannot multiply two or more numbers separately, right?

Comment: You're right that those are the two valid expansions, but I'm worried when you say "we cannot multiply two or more numbers separately", as that doesn't seem like a true description of the mistake you made. It's more like you tried to "distribute multiplication over multiplication", which is very much not allowed. Your motto should be "multiplication distributes over addition, and that's all!" (I'm including subtraction as a kind of addition, i.e. adding the negative).

Comment: Oops, you gave three expressions, and yes, they are all valid. And I'd describe the first expression as arising from distributing "multiplication by 3*6". You use words like "do" or "take", which are pretty non-specific, and I'd feel more certain that you got it if you described it as "distribute multiplication by <something>" each time. Perhaps that's what's in your mind when you describe it now, but I can't tell that from what you've written.

Comment: @JonathanZ Got it. Thanks for helping

Comment: I think our last comments crossed-posted each other! But in response to your last one: Cool. Glad it's clearer now.

Comment: @JonathanZ Yes, I will keep that in mind. I hated math during my school time but now I am learning it on my own from the very beginning. That's why I am getting all these silly doubts

Comment: Learning on your own can be really challenging, but it sounds like you're very determined. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have

$$3*6*(6+9-12)$$

you can solve it in many different ways.

1.You first multiply the numbers in brackets by 6,then sum them up and multiply by 3.

\begin{align}
&3 * 6 * (6+9-12)\\
&=3 * (6 * (6+9-12))\\
&=3 * (6 * 6+6 * 9+6*(-12))\\
&=3*(36+54-72)\\                                                     &=3*(90-72)\\
&=3*18\\
&=54
\end{align}

2.The same as in the 1. way,but you multiply with 3 first and 6 in the end.

3 * 6*(6+9-12)=6*(3*(6+9-12))=6*(3* 6+3* 9+3*(-12))=6*(18+27-36)=                                                     =6*9=54

3.You can first sum up the numbers in brackets,then multiply by 6 and 3,which is the same as if you multiply by 18.

3* 6* (6+9-12)=18* 3=54

4.You can first multiply 6 and 3, then multiply every number in brackets by 18 and then sum up.

6* 3* (6+9-12)=18* (6+9-12)=108+162-216=54

In all four examples you get the same answer.

What was  your mistake?

When you wrote

```
     3×6(6+9−12)=(3×6)+(3×9)+(3×(−12))+(6×6)+(6×9)+(6×(−12))
```

the part +(6×6)+(6×9)+(6×(−12)) was wrong.You should just multiply by 6.Whenever you multiply you can use each factor only once.In your case (6+9-12) is one factor so you can multiply it only once,by3, by 6 or by 18.But you can also distribute the multiplycation over all the numbers in the sum,but only once,with one factor.

Maybe you also mistook this distribution with multiplying forms like

```
                        (a+b)*(c+d)
```

where you actually need to multiply each number with all the others in the other brackets.In this case you could get

```
       (3×6)+(3×9)+(3×(−12))+(6×6)+(6×9)+(6×(−12))
```

if the evaluation was (3+6)*(6+9-12).

If you don't understand this last paragraph just ignore it,so it doesn't confuse you further.

Comment: I edited your first two formulas to use LaTeX. It makes them look a lot nicer, and it's pretty standard that people are expected to use LaTeX when posting here. If you hit the 'Edit', you can see how it's done - I've found it's not that difficult once you've seen some examples.

Comment: Thank you for explaining